# Java Reading CSV file into array but ignore first line

Tags: java, sql, csv

I have written the following codes, however I will need to skip the first line as it is the field name. My file here is cart.csv. When the code read the first line i will get errors.

cart.csv

```
Number,Item,Quantity
1,Book,10
2,Fruit,14
3,Toy,2
```

code

```
 try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] data = line.split(",");

                String sql = "INSERT INTO DB (Number,Item,Quantity) values (?, ?, ?)";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstmt.setString(1, data[0]);
                pstmt.setString(2, data[1]);
                pstmt.setString(3, data[2]);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Upload Completed");
    }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(POI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `readLine()` before the while loop to skip the first line.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
br.readLine(); //read the first line and throw it away
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
br.readLine() // Read first line and skip...
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { .......
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For CSV read use SuperCSV. Awesome library. You can just do something like below to skip header.

```
listReader = new CsvListReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILENAME), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
listReader.getHeader(true);
```

http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html

Comment: Okey. Then I think you have to just skip the first line when you read. I was suggesting you the library because using that you can also write your csv field validations for example if you want to check the quantity is not empty in a line you can do that very easily. But finally its your choice.